# How does one output bold text in Bash?

Tags: bash, console, formatting, echo

I'm writing a Bash script that prints some text to the screen:

```
echo "Some Text"
```

Can I format the text? I would like to make it bold.

Answer (score 599, accepted):

The most compatible way of doing this is using `tput` to discover the right sequences to send to the terminal:

```
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
```

then you can use the variables `$bold` and `$normal` to format things:

```
echo "this is ${bold}bold${normal} but this isn't"
```

gives

> this is **bold** but this isn't

Note that `normal` will turn off *all* formatting (so if you have other formatting - such as colours - that will be disabled, too).

Comment: That's pretty nifty. If I understand correctly, This is the same as inserting the escapes, but it would work in other terminals (not VT100).

Comment: That's correct - it looks up the appropriate codes according to the value of TERM.

Comment: If you have the need to underline text, you could add a variable. Notice, the backticks are being removed from comment formatting. Use the same format in the answer.

UNDERLINE=`tput smul`

Comment: `tput` is a great command with [lots of commands](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983251/24874) for many different tasks.

Comment: I'm trying to something similar to what the OP is doing, but with a `motd` file. How/where would I define the `$bold` and `$normal` variables in that instance?

Comment: @Matt I don't think that's possible, I think you'd have to hard code the escape sequences (e.g. `\033[1m`; see Michal Trybus's answer)

Comment: This tput command is much better than the escape characters. You do not need "-e" with echo and it works with the command read:
```read -p "this is ${bold}bold${normal} but this isn't"```

Comment: It didn't work exactly as @psmears explained. I had to use: `echo $bold"bold text"$normal"normal text"`. Using zsh on CentOS 7.

Comment: @DamonHill: The example works fine for me under zsh (CentOS 7). What problem were you experiencing? I wouldn't recommend putting the variables outside "" quotes, as you don't know what might be in them (eg if your script is running on some weird terminal where the control codes include a `*`, the shell will try to expand that as a glob and mess up the control sequence).

Comment: @psmears. when I used $(bold) the script showed errors like `/path/script: line 90: bold: command not found`

Comment: @DamonHill: Ah OK - look closely, it's not `$(bold)` it's `${bold}`, i.e. curly brackets rather than round ones :)

Comment: Oh, you're right. The problem are the glasses, not the characters!! Sorry, and thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: you may want to protect it, e.g.: `bold=$(tput bold 2>/dev/null)`

Comment: I tried to use it and on commandline this works. But when I try to write the echo-ed  command output to output.txt file then it does not write character in bolds. Any suggestions on how I can print output in bold in side .txt file

Comment: @Nin: How are you displaying the text file? If you're using `cat` you should see the bold text. If you're using `less` you'll need to use `less -R` to see the bold effect.

Comment: I @psmears, I found via hard way that .txt file extension perhaps doesn't support showing output in bold irrespective if I use cat or any other command. Tried to vi the .txt file and saw it doesn't show output in bold or any other style in .txt file. Thanks for offering help though

Comment: @Nin: Text files _can_ contain the control codes, but it depends what program you use to display the file whether the text will display as bold. If you use `cat` it will work. With `vi` or `vim` it will not work. With `less` it will only work if you specify the right option.

Comment: if you have a bash script you can define `bold() { echo -e "\033[1m$1\033[0m"; }` and then call it via `bold foo bar` which will print **foo bar**

Comment: @Heinrich: You'd want to do something like `echo "${bold}$1${normal}"` to retain the advantage of `tput`, namely that it can cope with different types of terminal.

Comment: @psmears my suggestion doesn't require `tput`, its more just referring about a general quick function you can define a bash script and then continuously call

Comment: @Heinrich: It will require `tput` _if you want it to work on different types of terminal_ - that's why this answer recommends using `tput`, because it will still work even if you have an obscure terminal with different control codes (or, probably more likely these days, the user has set up their environment so that "bold" displays on their screen in a way that they find more useful than the default).

Comment: The issue with this answer is that the $normal string here also resets any colors you have set, which likely is not expected if you are using colors too. For example: `"$(tput setaf 1)Red ${bold}bold${normal}no longer red$(tput sgr 0)"`.

Comment: @catchdave: That's true, though it's also true of all the other answers too, at time of writing! Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a widely-supported way of sending "bold off" in terminfo, even though at least some terminals do support it with `\E22m`. I've added a note to the answer, so that at least the behaviour is expected.

Answer (score 207):

In order to apply a style on your string, you can use a command like:

```
echo -e '\033[1mYOUR_STRING\033[0m'
```

Explanation:

- **echo -e** - The `-e` option means that escaped (backslashed) strings will be interpreted
- **\033** - escaped sequence represents beginning/ending of the style
- **lowercase m** - indicates the end of the sequence
- **1** - Bold attribute (see below for more)
- **[0m** - resets all attributes, colors, formatting, etc.

The possible integers are:

- **0** - Normal Style
- **1** - Bold
- **2** - Dim
- **3** - Italic
- **4** - Underlined
- **5** - Blinking
- **7** - Reverse
- **8** - Invisible

All this is per [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) but is implemented by absolute majority of terminal emulators out there. An alternative way to style output is to rely on [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) through use of the `tput` command. The latter will most likely output escape sequences which are ANSI anyway, unless you're at a really obscure and/or exotic type of terminal.

Comment: Good explanation. Was looking around for what functionality `[0m` offers and this explains it well

Comment: Though it should be `\033[0m`

Comment: **`3` - italic**, at least in konsole

Comment: One wishes Strikethrough was supported on Ubuntu and some of the other popular platforms.

Comment: Do you guys happen to know in which man page this mapping can be found?

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru man terminfo

Comment: The `man terminfo` mentions \E as escape sequence. Just tried it on Linux Lite and it seems to work

Comment: Note: in other languages the escape code (`\033`) may be different. [This page](https://notes.burke.libbey.me/ansi-escape-codes/) explains it nicely.

Answer (score 53):

I assume bash is running on a vt100-compatible terminal in which the user did not explicitly turn off the support for formatting.

First, turn on support for special characters in `echo`, using `-e` option. Later, use ansi escape sequence `ESC[1m`, like:

```
echo -e "\033[1mSome Text"
```

More on ansi escape sequences for example here: [ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php)

Comment: Thanks. I found some other lists of escape sequences, but the one you linked to is very extensive!

Comment: Don't forget to stop bold formatting at the end of the string: `echo -e "\033[1mSome Text\033[0m"` else the following lines of your terminal will be in bold too

Comment: This solution works even with PHP-CLI, that's an advantage against other solution.

Comment: if you have trouble remembering `\033` you can use `\e` like `echo -e "\e[1msome text\e[0m"`

Comment: Also note that octal litteral are forbidden in JS so we have to replace the `\033` part by `\x1b`

Comment: The octal escape sequence is allowed in JS (JavaScript)

Answer (score 25):

In theory like so:

```sh
# BOLD
$ echo -e "\033[1mThis is a BOLD line\033[0m"
This is a BOLD line

# Using tput
tput bold 
echo "This" #BOLD
tput sgr0 #Reset text attributes to normal without clear.
echo "This" #NORMAL

# UNDERLINE
$ echo -e "\033[4mThis is a underlined line.\033[0m"
This is a underlined line.
```

But in practice it may be interpreted as "high intensity" color instead.

(source: http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2008/01/ansi-escape-sequences-for-writing-text.html)