# Bold text in Java string

Tags: java

I just can't get it to work, I need to make my text bold, but everything I see on Google doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
drawLoadingText(percentage, (new StringBuilder()).append("Downloading "+downloadingText+""+s+": "+percentage+"% ").append("@ "+downloadSpeed+"Kb/s").toString());
```

Comment: `Hope anyone can help me out!` - how do you expect anybody to be able to help you without knowing the context of your question? Are you trying to display bold text on the console? Are you using Swing (or some other GUI? Are you displaying the text in a Swing component? Are you doing custom painting? Update your question to make it more reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what should be bold. But you could surround it with a `<b>` and `</b>` (there are a few assumptions in this statement<sup>1</sup>). Finally, I would prefer a call to [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) for implementing formatted text. Something like

```
drawLoadingText(percentage, String.format(
        "Downloading <b>%s</b> %s: %d%% @ %d KB/s", downloadingText, s,
        percentage, downloadSpeed));
```

<sup>1 <sub>Basically, I assumed you're drawing some text using a standardish [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html).</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have looked for this fo java code using ASCII table.

**\u001B[1m** <- Bold on

**\u001B[0m** <- Text Stuffs off

```
drawLoadingText(percentage, (new StringBuilder()).append("\u001B[1mDownloading\u001B[0m "+downloadingText+""+s+": "+percentage+"% ").append("@ "+downloadSpeed+"Kb/s").toString());
```

[this above its find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924697/how-does-one-output-bold-text-in-bash)

In order to apply a style on your string, you can use a command like:

```
echo -e '\033[1mYOUR_STRING\033[0m'
```

**Explanation:**

**echo -e** - The -e option means that escaped (backslashed) strings will be interpreted

**\033** - escaped sequence represents beginning/ending of the style
lowercase m - indicates the end of the sequence

**1** - Bold attribute (see below for more)

**[0m** - resets all attributes, colors, formatting, etc.

**The possible integers are:**

0 - Normal Style

1 - Bold

2 - Dim

3 - Italic

4 - Underlined

5 - Blinking

7 - Reverse

8 - Invisible