# Echo output is different from expected formatted output

Tags: bash, cygwin, echo

I'm using the following formatting for echo
[image: Screenshot of the terminal appearance]

It should output text that is both bold and underlined, but instead of making it bold it's giving a 'brighter' variant of color and takes the underlined code (4) as if it was cyan, resulting in Light Cyan text.

I'm using Cygwin's Bash on a windows 7 PC.

Edit: I've found a link that appears relevant to my case but I'm not sure how it applies since they're taking about the windows 10 update bash while I'm using Cygwin's [enter link description here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2027)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one output bold text in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924697/how-does-one-output-bold-text-in-bash)

Comment: replacing your `¥e` sequences by `\033` works for me

Comment: @Aserre I tried \033 and \E as well, the yen sign is the equivalent of backslash for the system locale I'm using and it hasn't proven an issue yet so I don't believe that is the problem but if there are known issues that arise due to changing system locale please do let know.

Comment: What terminal are you using ? Mintty produces the expect "Bold and underlined" while on CMD produces  cyan.

Comment: @matzeri Yes, this is exactly it, I found Mintty in my pc (within the cygwin directory/folders) and it produced the output I needed when entering the same command, I more or less understand that the shell and terminal are separate things, but then does that mean bash uses CMD by default? can I change that somehow? by the way I don't really specify a terminal(?) I just open the bash executable as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are running bash through the old cygwin.bat, so you are using the Windows Console as terminal, and not through the default Mintty that is a more advanced Terminal.

By default Cygwin setup install the "Cygwin Terminal" entry in the windows menu

The content of the menu entry is like

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

with path like

```
C:\cygwin64\bin
```

These items can be a also recreated at the last step of cygwin setup running.
There are two box entries :

> □ Create icon on Desktop
>   □ Add icon to Start Menu

If you enable them, both will be recreated

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my profile :

```
## NORMAL
export NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)

## FOREGROUND
export FGBLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
export FGRED=$(tput setaf 1)
export FGGREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
export FGYELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
export FGBLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
export FGMAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
export FGCYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
export FGWHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
export FGBRIGHT=$(tput bold)
export FGNORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
export FGBOLD=$(tput bold)

## BACKGROUND
export BGBLACK=$(tput setab 0)
export BGRED=$(tput setab 1)
export BGGREEN=$(tput setab 2)
export BGYELLOW=$(tput setab 3)
export BGBLUE=$(tput setab 4)
export BGMAGENTA=$(tput setab 5)
export BGCYAN=$(tput setab 6)
export BGWHITE=$(tput setab 7)

## SHAPE
export SHUNDERLINE=$(tput smul)
export SHBOLD=$(tput bold)
export SHSBOLD=$(tput smso)
```

So I can easily use it in the command line or in my scripts. For instance :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is ${FGRED}foreground red${NORMAL}"
echo "This is ${BGRED}background red${NORMAL}"
echo "This is ${FGYELLOW}${BGRED}background red and foreground yellow${NORMAL}"
echo "This is ${SHUNDERLINE}underlined${NORMAL}"
echo "This is ${FGCYAN}${SHUNDERLINE}cyan underlined${NORMAL}"
echo "This is ${SHBOLD}bold${NORMAL}"
echo "This is ${SHUNDERLINE}${SHBOLD}underlined bold${NORMAL}"
echo "This is ${FGBLUE}${SHBOLD}blue bold${NORMAL} and this ${FGBLUE} normal blue${NORMAL}"
echo "This is ${SHSBOLD}standout bold${NORMAL}"
```

Which results in outputs like this :

[image]

Hope its useful for you!