# How to add ACS_variables to Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, ncurses

I built a game with ncurses because of pdcurses' resizing problems i switched to cygwin. 
Compiled the game with cygwin and it worked almost perfectly.

1. Some acs_variables (i.e. ACS_DIAMOND) are seen as a question mark.
2. When i ran the game the cursor appears at the beginning of the snake (made a traditional snake game with c++) and also appears at the pause menu; 
   For example: >_ New Game .

2,5. There is also a frame in the window i've set it like this; 
box(window, char(219), 0);

-> top and bottom sides are displayed as straight line just as expected; However left and right sides, instead of char(219) there was blue and red lines, side by side.

I first made the game with visual studio and worked just normal except the resizing problem.

I've tried to change Character set to UTF-8  in the Text submenu of the cygwin, it didn't work.

In my code, i already set curs_set(0) function so cursor shouldn't have appeared in the game.

I am new to cygwin, looked over the internet but couldn't find a solution.
So any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is strange but when i ran the game from console , it runs smoothly; no cursor on the screen nor the special character problems but  when i ran it from .exe all the problems continue. What should i do to prevent this?

Comment: You told us nothing to understand the problem. What you mean from `ran it from .exe` ? I suspect your issue has the same root cause of this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539636/echo-output-is-different-from-expected-formatted-output/53553613#53553613

Comment: You should post your actual code, or a minimal subset that illustrates the problem. Also, what are "PDCurses' resizing problems"? Also, when you refer to "char(219)", I assume you mean the block character from code page 437 (et al.)? But then you refer to changing the character set to UTF-8... where that block definitely won't show up at 219...