# How to print bold text using printf?

Tags: bash, printf

I want to print bold text using `printf`.  How do I do it?

```
printf '%s\n' "\033[1m"bold_text"\033[0m"
```

doesn't work.  It displays:

```
\033[1mbold_text\033[0m
```

However, the same string works fine with `echo -e`:

```
echo -e "\033[1m"bold_text"\033[0m"
bold_text
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2924697/5291015 ? (not my dv)

Comment: `printf "\e[1;mbold_text\n\e[0m"`

Comment: I'd never hardcode escape sequences. Use the terminal capabilities.

Comment: @oguz I'd rather prefer you add it to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924697/how-does-one-output-bold-text-in-bash post to make it a generic duplicate covering all cases

Comment: I meant, people who are looking for way to use printf can use your answer. So that can be made a canonical duplicate in the future

Comment: `printf '%b\n' ` did the trick.  The linked answers seem to use `echo -e` everywhere.  I had seen those post before adding this question.

Comment: Not sure why the question should be downvoted.  When I searched for `bash printf bold` nothing good showed up on the site and hence I posted it as a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right answer is to use the `%b` format specifier instead of `%s`:

```
printf '%b\n' "\033[1m"bold_text"\033[0m"
```

From `help printf`:

> %b - expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument