# Can I push/pop attributes with tput?

Tags: terminfo, tput

In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2924697/8446), it uses the following (simplified):

```
echo "this is $(tput bold)bold$(tput sgr0) but this isn't"
```

But that `tput sgr0` resets *all* of the text attributes.

I'd like to output coloured text, with only some of it in bold. So I want something like this:

```
echo "$(tput setaf 1)this is red; $(tput bold)this is bold; $(tput unbold)this is red, but not bold"
```

But `tput unbold` isn't a thing.

Is there any way to push/pop the terminal attributes so that I could do something like the following?

```
echo "$(tput setaf 1)this is red; $(tput push; tput bold)this is bold; $(tput pop)this is red, but not bold"
```

Comment: I've got to ask. Why you need to do some kind of cherry picking of terminal attributes instead of just setting up your styling in a classic way with variables, like `colorbold=$(tput sgr0 && tput setaf 1 && tput bold)`, `colorunbold=$(tput sgr0 && tput setaf 1)`, etc.?

Comment: Because (1) that didn't occur to me; (2) in addition to the "red, red+bold, red" text, I've got "green, green+bold, green" text; having `bold`, `unbold-but-leave-the-color-alone` seems like a good fit for that.

Answer (score 1):

No - **`tput`** has no notion of push/pop.  Just ***set***: like a pun, **`tput`** is a more general tool than **`tset`**, as noted in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-HISTORY):

> - SVr3 replaced that, a year later, by a more extensive program whose
>   *init* and *reset*  subcommands  (more  than  half  the  program)  were
>   incorporated  from  the  reset  feature of BSD [**`tset`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h2-HISTORY) written by Eric
>   Allman.

**`tput`** does nothing like push/pop, because it would have to rely upon asking the terminal what the current video attributes are (something that only a minority of the terminals could do).

Some terminals could/can do this, e.g., the DEC VT420's [DECRQSS](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Device-Control-functions:DCS-$-q-Pt-ST.DF5) control mentioned in [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).  Most do not (even limiting this to xterm-imitators).

**`tput`** works with terminal capabilities; none of the predefined ones in [terminfo(5)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) deal with stacks.

That's not to say that someone might develop an application like **`tput`** which could work with a terminal that supports stacking, either by supporting push/pop or set/get controls.  (xterm does both).

Answer (score 0):

My `tput` has in the man page:

```
bold=`tput smso` offbold=`tput rmso`
     Set the shell variables bold, to begin stand-out mode sequence, and offbold, to  end  standout  mode  se‐
     quence,  for  the current terminal.  This might be followed by a prompt: echo "${bold}Please type in your
     name: ${offbold}\c"
```

So example would be:

```
echo "$(tput setaf 1)this is red; $(tput bold)this is bold; $(tput rmso)this is red, but not bold"
```

Comment: so... at which point do you suppose the state will ***pop*** back to a previously ***saved*** state?

Comment: On my Ubuntu/WSL2 installation, stand-out mode isn't bold: it's inverse. Also rmso doesn't undo 'bold', only 'smso'.